# Using an API cross domain to get XML

Tags: jquery, xml, cross-domain, xss

I'm trying to get data from [cdn.animenewsnetwork.com](http://cdn.animenewsnetwork.com) and information pertaining to the API is [here](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/api.php). How would I access this using jQuery?

When I'm in the chrome console on the domain, it is as simple as the following:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://cdn.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/api.xml?title=~jin",
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function(responseXML){
        console.log(responseXML);
    },
       error:function(results){
        console.log(results);
    }
});
```

I know the trick using `dataType: 'jsonp'`, but that doesn't work with this xml. How would I get past this?

Answer (score 0):

In short unless the API supports CORS or JSONP, you will have to proxy the content through a server you control. The API docs don't mention JSONP or CORS support, so, most likely, this is not supported.

Comment: If this isn't supported, then how would they expect anyone to get the data? The way you mentioned?

Comment: If this isn't supported, then they likely only expect the API to be called from another server.

Comment: Odd. They say it is for programmers, but I wouldn't imagine wanting such a hassle as having to do that. Do you have any advice for the proxying, maybe a tutorial?

Comment: You'll need to setup a server and write some code (using whatever language you are comfortable with).  Your browser-based ajax requests will need to delegate to your server, which will call the API in your question, and return the result to your app running in the browser.  Your server will be the API, as far as the browser is concerned.